# Panels inside a ScrollViewer

Tags: wpf, layout, mvvm

I got an interesting issue inside my wpf application.

I'm working with mvvm, and items are composed within a content control that bound to the view model.

For example:

```
<Shell> 
   <ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{Bidning SomeVM}"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Bidning SomeVM2}"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{Bidning SomeVM3}"/>
    </StackPanel>
   </ScrollViewer>

</Shell>
```

If the stack panel got only one item it works fine, but for some reason each view (resolved form vm) require much more space(height) than it actually need.

The views contains a GroupBox and a datagrid inside if it's matter.

So this is my problem, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried to remove stackpanel?

Comment: sll: and then what? I cant put more than one child..

Answer (score 1):

A StackPanel is going to measure it's children with Infinity in the direction of the Orientation, which is Vertical by default. So your items will be measured with an infinite height which essentially means they're going to size to content - e.g. the DataGrid will allocate, measure and arrange a record for every item in the list (assuming no constraints were set on the control). Note too that their will be no virtualization as a result since that relies on being measured with a specific constraint.

Note, even if you used a different panel you might get this behavior as the ScrollContentPresenter within the ScrollViewer will measure it's children with infinity if it is performing the scrolling - which will happen if the CanContentScroll is set to false or if the ItemsPanel doesn't implement IScrollInfo.

I'm not sure what type of layout you're looking to acheive so it's hard to offer any specific recommendations.

Comment: I'm using the scroll viewer for zooming, I want the three contents fill the visible screen size and when zooming the scroll should get in action and bars get visible.

Comment: How do you see that working when the DataGrid, etc. will likely have scrollbars? So just to be clear you want the three controls to each have a 3rd of the height of the window. So when you zoom, you want those controls to still be measured/arranged as if they are a 3rd of the height but to use a rendertransform, etc. to zoom in on the contents of each?